# Using nodeJs to scrape and check Ember.VERSION from website

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, web-scraping

I want to check **Ember.VERSION** from a list of websites, how can I check external URLs by using NodeJs?

Comment: Tell us what you've tried

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer), which allows you to simulate a browser, with the full DOM and access to Browser APIs.

Make sure you install it with `npm i -g puppeteer` or `npm init && npm i puppeteer --save` in a new folder. Then you can require and use it as follows:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52657134/using-nodejs-to-scrape-and-check-ember-version-from-website');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

This snippet will automatically execute when running it with `node filename.js`; you can change the structure to only fire when you call a function instead of an enclosed-ran setup.

To build more complex programs with puppeteer, you will need to be familiar with the [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) and the [puppeteer documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.9.0/docs/api.md).